# Dropdown - hide non Selected option and default option

Tags: html, angular, typescript, charts

i'm using chartJS and, beside showing default chart, i want to show only the chart thats selected on Combobox.
The problem is that i cant show default chart, and cant hide non selected values. 
i got the charts filled onInit, to have data when I open the page chart component. 
Im using a funtion onChange to pass the id of the canvas chart to show it, but cant hide the others.. Note that i can add always more chart types, like point charts etc...  Whats the best way to do it?? 
The code i have right now is that:

**.html**

*I dont know if **data-ng-model="barChart"** works on typescript or on that version of angular.. but the intention was to default barChart as showed chart when open the chart page*

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" data-ng-model="barChart">
 <option value="barChart" selected>{{'Bar Chart' | translate }}</option>
 <option value="chart2">{{'Line Chart' | translate }}</option>
 <option value="rdr">{{'Radar Chart' | translate }}</option>
 <option value="pp1">{{'Pie Chart' | translate }}</option>
</select>

<div class="card-block">
 <canvas id="barChart" hidden="true"></canvas>
 <canvas id="chart2" hidden="true"></canvas>
 <canvas id="rdr" hidden="true"></canvas>
 <canvas id="pp1" hidden="true"></canvas>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
    ngOnInit() 
{
      var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
      var cts = document.getElementById("chart2");
      var radar = document.getElementById("rdr");
      var pie = document.getElementById("pp1");

    // values to fill the chart 
    ...
     this.barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                   type: 'bar',
                   data: {
                     ...
        }
    ...
    }
}

    onChange(deviceValue) {
      this.select = deviceValue;
      document.getElementById(deviceValue).hidden = false;
    }

    ...
```

edit: 
this code starts with nothing showed, then when i select one chart on combobox, it shows the chart, but when i select other, despite show selected, doesnt  hide the other..

Comment: give me few mins i'll give you a resolution

Comment: i eddited the post to give the information of what my code does..

Comment: The charts are all updated with new values nicely, the problem here is to show only the chart type (bar, pie, radar, etc..) selected on combobox. i can hide them all and show the selected one, but never hide any.. so i end with all the charts displayed on the page.

Comment: can you check the answer I posted and see whether you can fix it or not

Comment: check my post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use angular binding to hide and display the charts.

.ts

```
chartTypeSelected: string = '';
```

---

```
<canvas id="barChart" [hidden] = "! chartTypeSelected == 'bar' "> </canvas>
<canvas id="rdr" [hidden] = "! chartTypeSelected == 'radar' "> </canvas>
<canvas id="chart2" [hidden] = "! chartTypeSelected == 'chart2' "> </canvas>

...
```

then on change

```
onChange(deviceValue) {
    this.chartTypeSelected = deviceValue;
 }
```

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've tryed it, but it didnt work.. 
added the barChartSelected on .ts, ngInit it false. On html added the [hidden] as showed on canvas, and on change toggled it.. but nothing shows.. :(

Comment: Bereket, it works this way, but if i add another charts, i have to add more 'else if's'.
is that a way that only show selected and hidde the rest, no matter how many? 
thank you.

Comment: Gud to hear that works.
Now wait me I will be back with best solution.

Comment: @Break how about now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

component.html

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" ng-model="barChart">
 <option value="barChart" selected>Bar Chart</option>
 <option value="chart2">Line Chart</option>
 <option value="rdr">Radar Chart</option>
 <option value="pp1">Pie Chart</option>
</select>

<div class="card-block">
 <canvas *ngIf="select=='barChart'" id="barChart"></canvas>
 <canvas *ngIf="select=='chart2'" id="chart2" ></canvas>
 <canvas *ngIf="select=='rdr'"  id="rdr"></canvas>
 <canvas *ngIf="select=='pp1'" id="pp1" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Can use both ways as shown below.

```
*ngIf="select==='pp1'"

*ngIf="select=='pp1'"
```

Since I don't have the chart.js with me, I have used dummy data in component.ts

**component.ts**

```
select='barChart';
barCharts=['barChart','chart2','rdr','pp1'];
onChange(deviceValue) {

            this.select = deviceValue;
            console.log(this.select);
}
```

I hope this will help you. If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: i've tryied woth *ng-if, but it's like data for charts are undefined, i can  choose by that wat, but it shows nothing, just the canvas fro the chart:
the element is created and replaced when i choose it on dropdown, but the chart doesn't show..

Answer (score 0):

@Suvethan Nantha, i tryed it, but my chart is filled on init, and when i use ng-if, i think the component go and re-do the values to fill the chart, i dont know, but it dont work the way you helped..

@bereket gebredingle, that way it doesn't show nothing, i console log it and the values are right..  "barChart - true" but doens't show nothing..  on html i've added {{barChartSelected}}  to check the value and it gives: true..

Is that a simple way to show selected and hide the others, no matter how many??

thank you for your answers

edit: it works this way, but the more charts i have the more else if i need to add (and variables etc.. maybe get confused on the near future..)

**.ts:**

```
barChartSelected : boolean = false;
radarChartSelected : boolean = false;
chart2Selected : boolean = false;
pp1ChartSelected : boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
 //default chart showed
 this.barChartSelected = true;
....
  }

onChange(deviceValue) {
        console.log(deviceValue);
        if(deviceValue === "barChart")
        {
            this.barChartSelected = true;
            this.chart2Selected = false;
            this.radarChartSelected = false;
            this.pp1ChartSelected = false;
        }
        else if(deviceValue === "chart2")
        {
            this.barChartSelected = false;
            this.chart2Selected = true;
            this.radarChartSelected = false;
            this.pp1ChartSelected = false;
        }
        else if(deviceValue === "rdr")
        {
            this.barChartSelected = false;
            this.chart2Selected = false;
            this.radarChartSelected = true;
            this.pp1ChartSelected = false;
        }
        else if(deviceValue === "pp1")
        {
            this.barChartSelected = false;
            this.chart2Selected = false;
            this.radarChartSelected = false;
            this.pp1ChartSelected = true;
        }

    }
```

**.html:**

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" data-ng-model="barChart">
  <option value="barChart" selected>{{'Bar Chart' | translate }}</option>
  <option value="chart2">{{'Line Chart' | translate }}</option>
  <option value="rdr">{{'Radar Chart' | translate }}</option>
  <option value="pp1">{{'Pie Chart' | translate }}</option>
</select>


<div class="card-block">
  <canvas id="barChart" [hidden] = "!barChartSelected"></canvas>
  <canvas id="chart2" [hidden] = "!chart2Selected"></canvas>
  <canvas id="rdr" [hidden] = "!radarChartSelected"></canvas>
  <canvas id="pp1" [hidden] = "!pp1ChartSelected"></canvas>
</div>
```

works, but it's efficient, the more charts i ass the more else if's and variables  i have to add

Comment: I have edited my answer and now in efficient way. Check it out.

Comment: in a best way i have implemented it check my answer.

Comment: You are welcome.
So why do not select my answer as right answer ? ;-)

Comment: done my friend, thank you for your time and help! ;)